# MySQL is hosed in 18.10

Tags: mysql, 18.10

I just ran across a new problem with MySQL in 18.10.

As far as I know, it was running fine after the 18.10 upgrade. Now, when I shutdown the system, it pauses trying to shutdown MySQL with a 10 minute timeout wait time!

If I reboot the computer, MySQL comes up broke, and won't let me restart/stop it, until I kill the MySQL process. Then I can start/restart/stop it fine. MythTV uses MySQL, and it seems to run fine.

Is there any chance that this has to do with the DST time change that just occurred, or the MySQL update that just occurred?

If I try to check/repair MySQL, like so:

`sudo mysqlcheck --all-databases -p`

it says:

`mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect.`

Using a password in the command line makes no difference, except the error indicates **password: YES**.

Comment: The errors you've shown so far just indicate you haven't given the correct root password, so mysqlcheck hasn't run.  If you've forgotten the password can you follow the instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) and then update with the mysqlcheck results after that?

Comment: @thomasrutter you're partially correct. It's a root password issue. I had also previously modified the mysql startup because of my SSD, and I'll write a more complete answer when I've fully verified the remainder of the fix. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two problems.

1. I was using the wrong MySQL root password. **I found the correct root password. Duh.**
2. Because I'm using a SSD, some services were starting up too early/quickly. MySQL and MythTV in my case. I wrote a quick fix for delaying the MySQL startup by 30 seconds. But when MySQL had a recent update, it broke my quick fix. I had disabled the standard MySQL startup, and used my own, and when the MySQL update was installed, it updated the standard MySQL startup and re-enabled it. **All I had to do was to disable the standard MySQL startup again.**

I **disabled** the standard mysql.service...

```
$ systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-12-11 00:25:52 PST; 4 days ago
 Main PID: 2053 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 38 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 292.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─2053 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Dec 11 00:25:51 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Dec 11 00:25:52 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
lines 1-11/11 (END)
```

I wrote a new service startup...

```
$ more /etc/systemd/system/mysql_delay_start.service 
[Unit]
Description=Delay start of MySQL / MariaDB

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysql_delay_start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Which runs this...

```
$ more /usr/bin/mysql_delay_start 
#!/bin/sh
sleep 30s
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```